# Django template loader not loading templates from file system. TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, templates

OS: Windows 10, Django: 1.10.4, Python: 3.5.2

[image]

In the above image the 
`django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` should be listed, but it is not listed.

Does this mean that it is not looking into the app directories?

My settings.py(Template section)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Installed app section from settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

My app directory structure:

- foo

  - foo

    - ...
    - urls.py
  - app_bar

    - ...
    - urls.py
  - db.sqlite3
  - manage.py

foo/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('app_bar.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

app_bar/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

I can provide more info if required.

P.S. I want to load a template from one of my installed apps. I am getting TemplateDoesNotExist error.

Comment: Maybe you put something into `DIRS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above image the  `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader` should be listed, but it is not listed.

[`filesystem.loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader) works only when `DIRS` option is set in the `TEMPLATES` setting. And, in your settings `DIRS` is set to empty list.

Since `APP_DIRS` is set to `True`, it is trying to look for the templates in the apps mentioned in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in this case `django.contrib.admin`. You are getting the error because the template doesn't exist in that directory.

You need to check if the template you are using in one of the APPS in your django project. If yes, then please include it in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I have followed the Django tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

So here once I do "python manage.py startapp app_bar". It should have made an entry in "INSTALLED_APPS" section, but it has not. I guess that is the main problem. Am I correct?

Comment: If your template is included in `app_bar` app then include that at the end of `INSTALLED_APPS`. If the template is in the django project directory then include that as well.

Comment: I added the app_bar entry in INSTALLED_APPS section and it worked. I believe it should be automatically added by Django. Maybe in future versions.